# Replacing spaces after any digit using re.sub

Tags: python

I am using the following code to try and replace any spaces found after a digit in a string derived from a regex with a comma:

```
mystring = re.sub('\d ', '\d,',mystring)
```

This however gives me an input of `6` and replaces it with `\d,`. What is the correct syntax I need to give me `6,` as my output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use capturing group to capture the digits which exists before the space. So that you could refer that particular digit in the replacement part.

```
mystring = re.sub(r'(\d) ', r'\1,',mystring)
```

**or**

Use positive lookbehind.

```
mystring = re.sub(r'(?<=\d) ', r',',mystring)
```